# control dc dc converter board with the microcontroller

Tags: microcontroller, pwm, dc-dc-converter, current-measurement, voltage-measurement

I want to control a bidirectional buck boost dc dc converter evaluation board [evaluation board](https://www.monolithicpower.com/en/mpq4210.html)using STM32 Nucleoboard [MCU](https://os.mbed.com/platforms/ST-Nucleo-F070RB/). The evaluation board is having only I2C interface. I am connecting a 12V lead acid battery at the output terminals of a converter board. I want to control the output of a converter board such that it delivers same voltage of the battery to charge.

1. I can measure the voltage of the battery using voltage divider or current sensor
2. I am thinking to use high side current sense amplifier for measuring the current. But my confusion is where and how to measure the current.
3. Using MCU I can generate PWM using duty cycle. But how to interface board and MCU.
   Can someone please help me in this task.

Thanks and Regards

Comment: _"I want to control a bidirectional buck boost dc dc"_ MOSFET-wise, the possibility is there to push power from output to input but with feedback sensing only on the output side, how do you plan to make it run bidirectionally?

Answer (score 2):

The question isn't really clear… however:

1. yes, you can read the battery voltage with a voltage divider, but the MPQ should already have a register for that;
2. you don't need an high side current sense, the MPQ already has the IMON signal and you only need to read it; the board conveniently has a pin that takes that out;
3. you do not need to generate a PWM, the whole sense of using a programmable power converter is that it does all the dirty work. You only tell it how many volts you want;

To interface to your STM32 you only need the ground and I2C signals; check if they are 3V compatible but they should.

Comment: but my project is to control the converter using external digital control using MCU. I was looking for bidirectional buck boost converter, but I could not find one in any company. To control the board there is already a Virtual bench for MPQ using I2C. Where I can monitor the output voltage, but I should do that with MCU.